# CMake: include a directory into parent from within a subdirectory (aka library)

Tags: cmake

I have a small project with this structure:

```
myproject/
    mylib/
        include/
        src/
    myprog/
        include/
        src/
```

I added a CmakeLists.txt file into *myproject* and added the subdirectory *mylib* and *myprog*. The subdirectories got a CMakeLists, too. Now, when I run cmake, both modules are built correctly, unless I want to use mylib in myprogram. I've found solutions where the global CmakeLists defines an `include_directories`. But I would prefer to define this in *mylib* such that *mylib/include* is added to the project' include path. I would like a project of submodules where each submodule defines it's sources and includes and the project's CMakeLists only connects the modules together. How can I do that? Is that what I try to achieve recommanded? (cmake newbie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `target_include_directories`. See http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html